# How to group comma-separated variables in the same column?

Tags: r

Here is my false data:

```
#> id   column                 
#> 1    blue, red, dog, cat
#> 2    red, blue, dog
#> 3    blue      
#> 4    red
#> 5    dog, cat   
#> 6    cat
#> 7    red, cat
#> 8    dog
#> 9    cat, red
#> 10   blue, cat
```

I want to tell R for example that `dog and cat = animal` and `red and blue = colour`. I want to basically count the number (and eventually percentage) of animals, colours and both.

```
#> id   column                 newcolumn
#> 1    blue, red, dog, cat    both
#> 2    red, blue, dog         both
#> 3    blue                   colour
#> 4    red                    colour
#> 5    dog, cat               animal
#> 6    cat                    animal
#> 7    red, cat               both
#> 8    dog                    animal
#> 9    cat, red               both
#> 10   blue, cat              both
```

So far I have only been able to total up the number of red, blue, dog and cat by doing the following:

```
column.string<-paste(df$column, collapse=",")
column.vector<-strsplit(column.string, ",")[[1]]
column.vector.clean<-gsub(" ", "", column.vector)
table(column.vector.clean)
```

Would be very grateful for help, here is my sample false data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), 
                 column = c("blue, red, dog, cat", "red, blue, dog", "blue", "red", "dog, cat", "cat", "red, cat", "dog", "cat, red", "blue, cat"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all possible `animal`s and `colour`s in a vector. Split `column` on comma and test :

```
animal <- c('dog', 'cat')
colour <- c('red', 'blue')

df$newcolumn <- sapply(strsplit(df$column, ',\\s*'), function(x) {
                 x <- x[x != "NA"]
                 if(!length(x)) return(NA)
                 if(all(x %in% animal)) 'animal'
                 else if(all(x %in% colour)) 'colour'
                 else 'both'
                 })

df
#   id              column newcolumn
#1   1 blue, red, dog, cat      both
#2   2      red, blue, dog      both
#3   3                blue    colour
#4   4                 red    colour
#5   5            dog, cat    animal
#6   6                 cat    animal
#7   7            red, cat      both
#8   8                 dog    animal
#9   9            cat, red      both
#10 10           blue, cat      both
```

To calculate the proportion, you can then use `prop.table` with `table` :

```
prop.table(table(df$newcolumn, useNA = "ifany"))

#animal   both colour 
#   0.3    0.5    0.2
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can separate the rows on comma, for each `id` create a `newcolumn` based on conditions and calculate the proportions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(column, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(newcolumn = case_when(all(column %in% animal) ~ 'animal', 
                                  all(column %in% colour) ~ 'colour', 
                                  TRUE ~ 'both'),
            column = toString(column)) %>%
  count(newcolumn) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the first solution but ended up with an error ```Error in strsplit(df$column, ",\\s*") : non-character argument``` Am I missing something? Do I have to install any packages?

Comment: No, that is because you have R version < 4.0.0 hence `column` is of class "factor". Run `df$column <- as.character(df$column)` first to convert it to character and then try the answer.

Comment: I have another question, what happens if there are 'NA' values? Can I exclude them from being counted as 'both' or are they excluded automatically?

Comment: If they are actual `NA` you can add a line `x <- na.omit(x)` at the start in `sapply` call before `if` to remove them.

Comment: Sorry, just to be sure, like this? ```df$newcolumn <- sapply(strsplit(df$column, ',\\s*'), function(x) { x <- na.omit(x) 
  if(all(x %in% animal)) 'animal'
  else if(all(x %in% colour)) 'colour'
  else 'both'
})```

Comment: I tried replacing the first value in the sample with NA but putting the x <- na.omit(x) unfortunately didn't exclude the NA, would be very grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: ```df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), column = c("NA", "red, blue, dog", "blue", "red", "dog, cat", "cat", "red, cat", "dog", "cat, red", "blue, cat"))```

Comment: Those are not actual `NA`s but string `"NA"`. See updated answer to remove them.